# How do I replace the delimiter in a series of paths that can contain that delimiter?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, delimiter

If I have the string:

```
path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
```

I've tried like this:

```
"path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt" -replace "&",";"
```

But it produces

```
path1=/path/me ; you/file.json;path2=/path/you ; me/file.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself so far? This looks like a pretty solvable problem if you aren't trying to solve it in as little Bytes as possible. Just use `-split "&"` and then join the parts together however you want

Comment: What is the specific condition?  It would be helpful if you'd describe the general problem you are trying to solve.  That is, is it safe to assume you're looking to handle not just `path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt` but any `string` with `pathx` values that are separated by `&` and may, themselves, contain `&`?  Will there always be `path1` and `path2`, or sometimes more, sometimes less?

Comment: @BACON yes there will be another path2, path3, etc. the possibility:
path1=/me & you/file.json&path2=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt

Answer (score 2):

The problem, of course, is that sometimes `&` *delimits* paths and sometimes it's *part of* a path.  A simple character replacement won't be able to tell which `&` is which, so we'll need to use some context to figure that out.

We know that when `&` delimits two paths that the next path will begin with a label of the form `pathX=`.  We can use the pattern `&(?=(path\d+=))` to match such `&` characters.  `(?=)` is a [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion), which means everything inside of it must follow the `&` but will not actually be matched (replaced).  `path\d+=` means the literal characters `path` followed by [one or more](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-one-or-more-times-) [digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#DigitCharacter) (`\d+`) followed by the literal character `=`.

```
PS> $pattern = '&(?=(path\d+=))'
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt;path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt
PS> '&path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
;path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&&&&&path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json&;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&&&&;path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt
```

Notice that a leading `&` (fourth test input) is replaced as expected because it is followed by the usual `path1=`, but a trailing `&` (fifth test input) and multiple consecutive `&` (last test input) are not.  If those cases should be treated as empty paths and not filenames that end in `&`, that can be accomplished with the pattern `&+(?=(path\d+=)|$)`.  `&+` will now match [one or more](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-one-or-more-times-) `&`, and adding `|$` will [also match](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#Either_Or) `&` occurring at the [end of the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#End).

```
PS> $pattern = '&+(?=(path\d+=)|$)'
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt;path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt
PS> '&path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
;path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt;
PS> 'path1=/path/me & you/file.json&&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt&&&&&path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt' -replace $pattern, ';'
path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt;path3=/folder/R & B/ me & you/file.txt
```

Comment: Nice one (+1), IMO the display would benefit from a here string with all variants and doing one `-replace` on that - looks a bit crowded now.

Comment: @Levi Did this end up either solving your problem or getting you started in the right direction?

Comment: @Levi Glad to hear it.  Remember that on any answer you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) it if you found it helpful/unhelpful, and on [your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that best helped you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always need some fancy one line of code to do everything in one go.

`$test = $('path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt' -split "&");
$test[0] + "&" + $test[1] + ";" + $test[2] + "&" + $test[3]`

Comment: This assumes that the input `string` always contains `path1` and `path2`, and that both paths contain exactly one `&`.

Comment: @BACON Yes it does.